# Fatal Error: Index Out Of Range with Bundled Text File

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, uitableview, swift3

I am having trouble accessing the data from a bundled text file. The code works with menuInfo is [0] but not when it is a number higher than that. The goal of this code is to take the bundled text file and use its info to fill a tableview. I have tried other suggestions such as refreshing the tableview and checking the .count of my array.

What is interesting is that when I am in debug mode Xcode shows readings as having 533 values which is correct as it is the txt file contents separated by new line. But in the next line menuInfo has 1 value which is [0]=(String)"" . I think this line is my problem but I do not know why.

Non-Working Code:

```
class BreakMenuTableViewController: UITableViewController {    
    var dictMenu=[String:String]()
    var arrayMenu=NSMutableArray()
    let bundle=Bundle.main

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let path=bundle.path(forResource: "TU_Break", ofType: "txt")

        let filemgr=FileManager.default
        if filemgr.fileExists(atPath: path!){
            do{
                let fullText = try String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: .utf8)
                let readings=fullText.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.newlines) as [String]
                for i in 1..<readings.count {
                    let menuInfo=readings[i].components(separatedBy: "\t")

                    if menuInfo.count > 0 {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }

                    dictMenu["Day"] = "\(menuInfo[0])"
                    dictMenu["Menu"] = "\(menuInfo[1])"
                    dictMenu["Food"] = "\(menuInfo[2])"

                    arrayMenu.add(dictMenu)
                }
            }catch let error as NSError {
                    print("Error:\(error)")
            }
        }
    }
```

This is in Xcode 8.3. The error happens when I try to use dictMenu["Menu"] = "(menuInfo[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cs9OQ.png)])" When it hits this line I get the fatal error. I have attached a picture of txt file for reference.[image: TU_Break.txt]

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: You should check `menuInfo.count`, `if menuInfo.count >= 1 {//then you can do menuInfo[0]}  if menuInfo.count >= 2 {//then you can do menuInfo[1]}  if menuInfo.count >= 3 {//then you can do menuInfo[2]}`.

Comment: Use the debugger to check the contents of `readings[i]` to see what the expected components are.  (Does it truly contain tab characters, for example?)

Comment: @Larme `menuInfo.count is >=1` So I dont think that is a problem.

Comment: @PhillipMills I think the problem is in `readings`. `readings[0]` is the menu data I want `"Mon\tCOMFORT\tGrits"` separated by tabs. However, `readings[1]` is just `""`. It continues so each even [ ] is the data I want and each odd [ ] is "". Is there a way to fix this, I've been at it for a few days.

Comment: Take the next step back and examine `fullText`.  Do the file lines have multiple line terminators, perhaps?

Comment: There were multiple line terminators but that wasn't the problem. There was an empty array element that I didn't notice that needed to be filtered out. The code is working as of now. Thanks for your help!